# SQL Server: partial search on integer column

Tags: sql-server

I have an integer column in my database and I want to perform partial search on that integer.
Eg:

```
Column values:
1234, 1345, 167, 1236
```

Example queries and results:

```
 "12" - 1234, 1236
 "1" -  1234, 1345, 167, 1236
```

Comment: What's the point of such a query? Did you use an integer to store what's essentially a hierarchical path? It would be better to use a string instead, or the purpose-built type `hierarchyid`

Comment: If you used a string that encoded each hierarchy level as a fixed-length string, eg `01.02.05.05` you could use `LIKE '01.02%` to find all nodes bellow `01.02` taking advantage of any indexes on that field `LIKE 'abc%` is essentially a range search that can be accelerated by an index. `hierarchyid` works the same way, except it can encode larger values, takes less space and offers convenience functions to retrieve the level, children of a specific node, parent nodes etc

Answer (score 2):

You *could* cast the integer value to text, and then do a `LIKE` comparison, e.g.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CAST(int_col AS varchar(max)) LIKE '12%';
```

However, having the need to do this cast often might imply that your `int_col` integer column should in fact really be some kind of text column.  Even if you had an index on `int_col`, the above query couldn't use it.